# Alternates to tab key to expand sublime text 2 snippers when also using Emmet?

Tags: sublimetext2, emmet

I've been using Sublime Text 2 and have recently incorporated Emmet into my workflow.  Since Emmet takes over the tab key for expanding it's template is there a way to set up an alternate keyboard short cut to expand standard sublime snippets?  The only option I've been able is to search for the snippet in the command pallete.

**Background**

I understand I can re-map the Emmet completion to a new keyboard shortcut, say Ctrl-E.  In practice I use Emmet snippets 90% of the time and Sublime snippets 10% of the time, so I'd like to keep the speed of the tab key for Emmet, but also get a short cut key that expands sublime snippets.

**Update**

To illustrate what I'm looking for, imagine I have a sublime snippet for `hw` that expands to `<p>Hello World!</p>`, and a emmet snippet `hw` that expands to `<hello>World</hello>`.  I'd like to be able to type `hw+tab` and get the emmet snippet and say `hw+ctrl+tab` to get the sublime snippet.  A good suggestion was to use the native `insert_best_completion` but that would result in `<hw></hw>`

Comment: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#tab-key-handler

Comment: @SergeyChikuyonok thanks for the link, I was aware of that, I'm looking for the opposite.  I don't want to disable the emmet tab expansion and use an alternate, I want to find an alternate route for sublime text 2 tab expansion.  About 90% of the time I'm expanding an emmet snippet, and 10% of the time I'm expanding a sublime text 2 snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind `insert_best_completion` command to to shortcut. The example keybinding config may look like this:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+tab"], "command": "insert_best_completion" }
```

It will insert best completion with Ctrl+Tab shortcut. You can add this command into `Preferences > Key Bindings – User` file.

For more info, read

- https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/customization/key_bindings.html
- https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/commands.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's exactly what I'm going for, but haven't been able to figure out how to replicate the tab snippet completion.  Say I have an emmet snippet for hw => <hello>World</hello>, a sublime text snippet for hw => <p>Hello World!</p>.  If I type "hw" and then ctrl-tab, that gives me <hw></hw>, when I'm hoping to get <p>Hello World!</p>.  It seems like this might not be possible :(

Answer (score 1):

Have the same issue myself.

So far, for user generated snippets I have come across using a forward slash after the keyword.  This allows the tab key to then be used.

```
<tabTrigger>hello/</tabTrigger>
```

Produces the desired result instead of

```
<hello></hello>
```